# AVPlayer: Unable to play() a mpg video

Tags: swift, avplayer

The following simple class doesn't play a video URL.  What I get is a black empty screen.  Why?

```
import Foundation
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class EditShowVideoViewController:AVPlayerViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            var error: NSError?
            if let urlString = gBlissMedium!.mediumURL {
                let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
                player = AVPlayer(URL:url)
            }
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            player.play()
        }
        override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        }

        override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
```

> (lldb) po urlString
>   "http://files.parsetfss.com/6b8388b7-14c6-431a-a795-2b33f9d47081/tfss-56cf2c67-111c-4724-8e63-3755fe1b85f7-hst_1.mpg"

Comment: player should be a member variable, not local

Comment: I've created an iVar/member var; but doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let urlString = gBlissMedium!.mediumURL {
                let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
                player = AVPlayer(URL:url)
}
```

here `player` is being defined locally in `viewDidLoad`, it should be an instance variable of the class